# Create a page from a template using the Notion API

Tags: notion-api

Is it possible to create a page in a database from scratch using an existing template through the Notion API?
I could not find any mention of it in the API docs.

Comment: I'm also trying to figure this out.  I don't see an endpoint for this, so I suspect you'll have to grab the template props, then the block children, then combine them and make a new page in the table.

Answer (score 2):

As of the current version of the API (Notion-Version: 2021-05-13) the API does not support a create database endpoint, nor does the API support templates at this time.

Comment: This is no longer true, right?